# Different python modules give identical co_code objects

Tags: python

Why would the following two Python code modules, when compiled into pyc form, have identical `co_code` attributes?

Module 1:

```
def foo():
    response = 'success'

    success = 'success' in response

    if not success:
        raise Exception('failure: %s' % response)
```

Module 2:

```
def foo():
    response = 'success'

    success = 'success' in response

    if not success:
        if 'failure: ' in response:
            reason = response[len('failure: '):]
            raise Exception('failure: %s' % reason)

        else:
            raise Exception('neither success nor failure found in response')
```

If the only difference were, say, in string literals, I can see why the `co_code` attributes would be identical.  But these two modules seem significantly different.

Here's the code I'm using to perform the comparison:

```
import marshal
import sys

def get_pyc_code(path):
    '''Extract code object from compiled .pyc file.'''

    try:
        handle = open(path, 'rb')

    except IOError as ex:
        print str(ex)
        sys.exit()

    magic = handle.read(4)
    moddate = handle.read(4)

    code = marshal.load(handle)
    handle.close()
    return code

def compare_codes(path1, path2):
    '''
    Compare the full code objects and co_code attributes of pyc files
    path1 and path2.
    '''

    code1 = get_pyc_code(path1)
    code2 = get_pyc_code(path2)

    code_same_full = (code1 == code2)
    code_same_attr = (code1.co_code == code2.co_code)

    if code_same_full and code_same_attr:
        print 'pyc files are identical'

    else:
        print('full code objects the same: %s' % code_same_full)
        print('co_code attributes the same: %s' % code_same_attr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        compare_codes(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

    else:
        print('usage: %s foo.pyc bar.pyc' % sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the module-level code object itself doesn't represent the code of functions inside it.  You can see what the code is if you use `dis` (I used `c1` here for the code object):

```
>>> dis.dis(c1)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object foo at 000000000234D230, file "m1", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (foo)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that the module code is the same for both, because both modules do nothing but define a single function.  The code of the *functions* is different, but that's not what you're looking at here.

Comment: Would comparing the code objects, instead of just the `co_code` attributes, be enough to identify non-identical modules?

Comment: @JohnGordon: I don't know.  It seems to work, but I don't really know how equality comparisons are defined on code objects.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm working on a software application that is delivered as compiled pyc files packaged inside an RPM.  I'm trying to come up with a way of comparing two such RPM files to identify any changes between the two.